# Error - Importing google play service

Tags: android, location, google-geolocation

I'm learning android, I want to use google play service for location service.

I am following :  http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/

I had import library `google-play-service_lib` as this example asks for.  But the following error shows in res/values-v21 & `res/values-v11` 
please help if anyone knows this.  Thank you.

Error-1

```
Description : error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name `'@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.`

Resource : appinvite_styles.xml
Path : /google-play-services_lib/res/values-v21 
Location : line 5   
Type : Android AAPT Problem
```

Error-2

```
Description : error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name `'@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.`

Resource : appinvite_styles.xml 
Path : /google-play-services_lib/res/values-v11 
Location : line 5   
Type : Android AAPT Problem
```

Here's my file res/values-v11

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- Base preview application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.AppInvite.Preview.Base" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar"/>

</resources>
```

Here's my file res/values-v21

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- Base preview application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.AppInvite.Preview.Base" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar"/>

</resources>
```

Comment: please tell me why this Down vote ? I'm new user in this site . so plz tell me if i am making mistake in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, finally i found the solution of this.
it just need to import the `android-support-v7-appcompat`
the reason why it gives error is it may not find the style using as parent ,

```
parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar"

parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar"
```

just do , **(File -> Import -> Location of android sdk -> sdk -> extras -> android -> support -> v7 -> appcompat)**

it works for me , it may possible that it is not the only reason of this error so please read comments below if any. 
thank you , hope it helps.

Comment: Then I'm getting bunch of errors with appcompat project itself.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change you google play service target

1) Right click on google play service project 
2) Select property
3) Set Target 21
Hope help you